# C# interface constraints

Tags: c#, interface

I have an interface as follows:

```
public interface IOutlinesComputable
{
    Tuple<Point,Point> getBoundingBox();
}
```

Furthermore I have an abstract class *Shape* implementing this interface and two subclasses of *Shape*: *SimpleShape* and *GroupShapes* - the latter one containing a list of *Shape*s.

My client code obtains a list of *IOutlinesComputable*s. I would like to go through this list and check for each pair of *IOutlinesComputable*s if their bounding boxes overlap. If so, I want to merge these: In the case of shapes by creating a new instance of *GroupShapes* and adding the overlapping *Shape*s to it.

Can I state in the interface that the class A implementing *IOutlinesComputable* has to have one subclass *B* which references a list of *A*s, so that I can do this process for all objects being structured like *Shape*, *SimpleShape* and *GroupShapes*?

I'm just realizing that I have to take care that all objects in the *IOutlinesComputable* list are of the same type *A* (so it is getting less nice), but anyway I would like to know if something like this is possible or how to design this the best way.

Comment: rethink your relationships. "GroupShapes" is really a `List<SimpleShape>`

Comment: You may think of any Shape as having a list of overlapping shapes. It just so happens that there some Shapes which has an empty list, and we say that they are *simple*. Edit: I'm thinking your shapes are immutable. Edit 2: if you have a custom class for `List<SimpleShape>` (as stated in the comment below) your shape class can have a property of that, and the so called *simple* shape may have it null.

Comment: >user700390 Yes, but I have additional methods related to `List<SimpleShape>` (which I omitted here) which I think a class is a good place for.

Comment: Adding `IEnumerable<IOutlinesComputable> ChildSahpes()` to interface is very common way to express that (with most returning `Enumerable.Empty<IOutlinesComputable>()` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I state in the interface that the class A implementing IOutlinesComputable has to have one subclass B which references a list of As, so that I can do this process for all objects being structured like Shape, SimpleShape and GroupShapes?

No, there's no way to express such a constraint in the language.